# Difference between [CLLocation] and CLLocation

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation

I am trying  to find the distance between a location that I am grabbing from a user and a location that I hard coded, but I am getting a error can't convert [CLLocation] to CLLocation.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations[0].coordinate.latitude, longitude: locations[0].coordinate.longitude)
     longitude = locations[0].coordinate.longitude
     latitude = locations[0].coordinate.latitude
    let coordinate₀ = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 5.0)

    let distanceInMeters = coordinate₀.distance(from: locations)
    print(distanceInMeters)
}
```

Comment: `[CLLocation]` is an array of `CLLocation`

Comment: Access the last object from the `locations` array to get the current location of user.

Comment: Thank you for this. I can't believe I did not realize this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you still don't understand the basics of the Swift language. Perhaps you should head over [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) and read up on the Swift documentation first.

You are using an array of CLLocation whereas the function `distance(from: )` takes in an argument of a single CLLocation.

It looks like that you want to do is to replace your

```
let distanceInMeters = coordinate.distance(from: locations)
```

To `let distanceInMeters = coordinate.distance(from: location)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `location` instead of `locations` in the below line

```
let distanceInMeters = coordinate₀.distance(from: locations)
```

Answer (score 0):

[CLLocation] is an array of CLLocation, try below

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations[0].coordinate.latitude, longitude: locations[0].coordinate.longitude)
     let loc = locations[0]
     longitude = loc[0].coordinate.longitude
     latitude = loc[0].coordinate.latitude
    let coordinate₀ = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 5.0)

    let distanceInMeters = coordinate₀.distance(from: loc)
    print(distanceInMeters)
}
```